# Cannot read property 'toFixed' of undefined. Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand why my code block doesn't work. I am using JQuery as well as vanilla JS.

Here's my code.

```js
 // update every 1 second on time.
  setInterval(function() {
    // get current time and duration of entire video
    let getTimePaused = video.currentTime;
    let vidTime = getTimePaused.toFixed(0);
    let formatTime = minTommss(vidTime);
    $(".timeLeft").text(
      minTommss(vidTime / 60) + " - " + minTommss((video.duration / 60) + 0.01)
    );
  }, 1000);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand what the error means? What is the value of `video`?

Comment: Please post the rest of your code,

Comment: @FelixKling I do understand it. However, I'm not sure why I'm getting it. Is it because I need to parseInt something?

Comment: You code doesn't show where `video` comes from at all, you're not passing it into the function, so why would anyone (including you) assume that `video.currentTime` exists as a value?

Comment: *"Is it because I need to parseInt something?"* No. The error means that `video` is a value that doesn't have a property `currentTime`. The fix is to either make sure that `video` is the value you need or to access the correct property. There is not much more we can say about it without having more context.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans But if video wasn't available in the function it would already throw an error when accessing currentTime

Comment: @StefanBlamberg I never said `video` wasn't available, I said we, as readers of this question and code, have _no idea what video is_ and so it might be an empty string for all we know, or an empty object, or actually an `<a>` element, or even another function, or who knows what else. The code, as shown in this question, is not complete, and so this is [not a good question](/help/how-to-ask) yet.

Answer (score 3):

I actually fixed it.

In my case, the problem didn't have anything to do with `toFixed()`.

My problem was due to mixing JQuery and Vanilla Javascript.

Like this,

```js
let video = $(".video");

video.on("timeupdate", function() {
    let colorPos = video.currentTime / video.duration;
    color.style.width = colorPos * 100 + "%";
    if (video.ended) {
      btn.className = "replay";
    }
  });
```

Solution

```js
let video = document.querySelector(".video");

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    let colorPos = video.currentTime / video.duration;
    color.style.width = colorPos * 100 + "%";
    if (video.ended) {
      btn.className = "replay";
    }
  });
```

Comment: As I said, the error means that the value of `getTimePaused` is `undefined`, which means that `video` doesn't have the property `currentTime`. jQuery objects don't have that property. Another solution would have been to use `video[0].currentTime`. And that's why it was important to tell us what the value of `video` is. If we had known, we could have immediately pointed out what was wrong.

Comment: can you please update your _question_ with the code that you decided to show here, too?